# Start cell from same page, iText

Tags: java, itext

I want to add two rows in my report header and comment.

```
    mainTable.addCell(headingCell);
    mainTable.addCell(commentCell);
```

Now when i am adding comment which have text more than total space on the page, it is starting comment from new page instead of starting from same page. from next page it is breaking text for each page but shifting from first page.

I want to start comment from first page and flow to next pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worrking now when i set mainTable.setSplitLate(false); after adding cells.